# how to get return value from a table in python

Tags: python

I have a list like

```
NTCAN_SUCCESS=0
NTCAN_RX_TIMEOUT=-1
NTCAN_TX_TIMEOUT=-2
NTCAN_CONTR_BUSOFF=-3
```

In my program when i used return statement

```
def can_baudrate(self, l_baud=0x0000008):    
    l_baud = ctypes.c_long(l_baud)
    status = self.can_dll.canSetBaudrate(self._handle, l_baud)
    return status
```

it gives status number like `(0,-1,-2 or -3)` which is according to the above list. How do I get a description like `NTCANSUCCESS` and so on according to return status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can us a `dict` to map the status codes to status messages:

```
>>> verbose_status={0:"NTCAN_SUCCESS",
                   -1:"NTCAN_RX_TIMEOUT",
                   -2:"NTCAN_TX_TIMEOUT",
                   -3:"NTCAN_CONTR_BUSOFF"}
>>> print(verbose_status[-2])
NTCAN_TX_TIMEOUT
```

Comment: Thank you @ Christian König